# Class name by define directive. Possible?

Tags: c++, class, c-preprocessor

Can I create a class and assign his name from an external source?

ex:

```
// Something like this
#define ClassName Clients

class ClassName
{
    public:
    ClassName();
};

ClassName::ClassName()
{
    //
}
```

Edit: my real code
(That way, in the XML output of the DUnit framework, my the test name is TestName, not DatabaseTest)

```
#define TestName DatabaseTest

namespace TestName
{
    class TTest : public TTestCase
    {
        public:
        __fastcall virtual TTest(System::String name) : TTestCase(name)
        {
        }
        virtual void __fastcall SetUp();
        virtual void __fastcall TearDown();

        __published:
        void __fastcall t1();
    };

    void __fastcall TTest::SetUp()
    {
    }

    void __fastcall TTest::TearDown()
    {
    }

    void __fastcall TTest::t1()
    {
        CheckEquals(1,0);
    }
}

class TTestName : public TestName::TTest
{

};

static void registerTests()
{
    Testframework::RegisterTest(TTestName::Suite());
}
```

Comment: you should at least try it before posting - would you have done so, you could have figured out yourself that the answer is yes

Comment: Yes, and in general, you shouldn't.

Comment: Actually didn't work. Compiled with the "ClassName" name.

Comment: @Stew actually, it does work: http://ideone.com/10Jg9

Comment: No, it compiles with the "Clients" name: http://ideone.com/JLfrm

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes and ClassName http://ideone.com/7OyfH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although absolutely not recommended, it is possible. The C (or C++) preprocessors replace whatever name they can with the specified defined value without caring for their meaning. After all, they are just preprocessors.

So, say you have this header file:

generic_class.h

```
class ClassName
{
    public:
    ClassName()
    {
        //
    }
};
```

You can get multiple instances of this class like this:

```
#define ClassName Server
#include "generic_class.h"
#undef ClassName

#define ClassName Clients
#include "generic_class.h"
#undef ClassName
```

Note that you should not add guards to the header.

**This code is terrible of course.**

Comment: I will accept your answer, good example, but didn't work for my case. Compiles, but my log file registers "ClassName" =/

Comment: Can you tell me how you logged the class name and where you did that?

Comment: I don't know DUnit, but could be that it reads the name from the class directly on its own, with no regards of what C++ preprocessor is doing. After all, no program expects the name of the class to be changed by a macro. Is it possible for you to log the name of the class in its constructor so you overlook what DUnit is telling you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Pre-processing takes place before compilation.

Your compiler will basically see

```
class Clients
{
    public:
    Clients();
};

Clients::Clients()
{
    //
}
```

But why would you want this? Is there some underlying issue you're trying to solve? I'm sure there are better ways.

Comment: I'm trying to padronize my unit testing. I will update my post with code example.